# Using multiple variables to create a Transport Rule

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, powershell-4.0

I am having an issue getting a piece of code working and would love some help with this.
I am confident this will be super easy for someone else.

Basically, I am trying to setup a script to create (and eventually update) a new exchange transport rule using two variables:

- $Displaynames
- $Emails

The issue I have is that I can't seem to find a way to utilize both variables at the same time.

I know I could get around this by first exporting my results into a CSV and then re-importing them each time, but I am sure there must be a better way.

Here's the problematic part of the script:

```
$ruleName = "My Rule"
$ruleHtml = "My html code"
$rule = Get-TransportRule | Where-Object {$_.Identity -contains $ruleName}
$DisplayNames = (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited).DisplayName
$Emails = (Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Select-Object displayname -expandproperty emailaddresses).SMTPAddress

New-TransportRule -Name $ruleName -Priority 0 -FromScope "NotInOrganization" -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerLocation "Prepend" -HeaderMatchesMessageHeader From -HeaderMatchesPatterns $Displaynames -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerText $ruleHtml
```

I've tried using -HeaderMatchesPatterns "$Displaynames","Emails" and various ways of turning the two variables into a single one, but still no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a lightbulb moment a bit later and ended up joining the two strings. Here's the end result:

```
$AllRecipients = $DisplayNames+$Emails
New-TransportRule -Name $ruleName -Priority 0 -FromScope "NotInOrganization" -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerLocation "Prepend" -HeaderMatchesMessageHeader From -HeaderMatchesPatterns $AllRecipients -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerText $ruleHtml
```

This does the trick.

I still wouldn't mind seeing if there's a better way of doing this in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$VN = "Mike.*Meyer"
$NV = "Meyer.*Mike"

New-TransportRule -Name "Test123456" -HeaderMatchesPatterns $VN,$NV -HeaderMatchesMessageHeader "From"
```

Works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).